# How to get views machine name in `block--views-block-html.twig` file?

Tags: views, theming, 8, blocks

I've create views as block. Then i tried to theme my views block by altering `block--views-block-html.twig` file. I've struggled to get views machine name in this file. I need views machine name for some reason. So any other solutions to get views machine name?

Answer (score 1):

Views machine name would be: /admin/structure/views/view/**frontpage**.

You can edit/change the view name on right corner: *Edit view name / description*.

You can override the template name using below.

- `[base template name]--[view machine name]--[view display id].html.twig`
- `[base template name]--[view machine name]--[view display type].html.twig`

So this would be:

- `views-view--frontpage--page.html.twig`

or:

- `views-view--frontpage--block.html.twig`

There is no theme information is displayed with D8 views as D7 views was having the those information.

Please refer the [reference page](http://redcrackle.com/blog/drupal-8/theme-views-templates).

Comment: Yes i know this. But i want to get views machine name inside the block--views-block-html.twig file

Comment: Please refer updated answer.

Comment: You lead me to choose theme file. Please read question carefully. I want to know how to get views machine name inside block--views-block-html.twig file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the ID with:

```
$variables['view']->id();
```

...but to do that, you need to preprocess the block/view; in my case, I needed to grab the machine name of a view that I was preprocessing using `template_chn_preprocess_views_view()`.

See the other options/methods you can access inside [`ViewExecutable`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/class/ViewExecutable/8.2.x).

Answer (score 0):

This would help someone still looking for adding a block template suggestion with View's machine name.

You should be able to get the View ID with `$variables['elements']['content']['#view_id]` if exists.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function my_theme_name_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $content = $variables['elements']['content'];

  // Add a common template suggestion for `View ID` view.
  if (isset($content['#view_id']) && $content['#view_id'] === 'view_id') {
    $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $content['#view_id'];
  }
}
```